# Executing a Query in ADODB in VB6

Tags: sql, vb6, adodb

I have a program in Visual Basic 6 thats listens to a ComPort and generates SQL Querys based on the data it recieves. Im using ADODB as my Database link of choice.

Currently im trying this:

```
' Initiate Database Connection
  Call dbConn
  results.Open SQLQueryfeld(s), cn
  Debug.Print (results.GetString)
  Debug.Print ("SQL Statement  " & SQLQueryfeld(s) & "  wurde erfolgreich ausgeführt")
  results.Close
```

Which gives me a "This operation is not permitted on a closed object" on the first Debug.Print line.

dbConn is a public function that creates an ADODB connection object named cn
results is initiated in the head of the function the code is from as

```
Dim results as New ADODB.Recordset
```

The end goal here is: Execute a INSERT sql statement (stored in string array SQLQueryfeld(s) ) and get a return wether or not it was successful. Im open to any other way of doing this, too, but it must use ADODB.

Here is some other code from the same project that works fine:

```
    Call dbConn

SQL = "SELECT Name FROM Personen WHERE Eintrag=" & Personalid & " "
rs.Open SQL, cn

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
tmp_name = rs.GetString
tmp_name = Replace(tmp_name, Chr(13), "")
tmp_name = Replace(tmp_name, Chr(10), "")
tmp_name = Replace(tmp_name, vbCrLf, "")
```

Comment: shouldnt you use assign variable cn the connection. Try to remove line call dbconn and use cn = dbConn

Comment: check the `cn.state` before recordset

Comment: I must add that call dbConn works in other, similar code forms with SELECT instead of INSERT statements

Comment: Also cn is a global public variable that is a ADODB Connection Object.

Comment: dcConn initiates the variable.

Comment: can you debug and check if you are able to get cn filled with connection?

Comment: The error is quite clear that your connection is closed

Comment: I added some other code from the same project that works fine with the same call to dbConn.

Comment: i suggest please check variable cn is getting active connection. It doesnt matter if its working on other page or not

Comment: Adding a debug print for cn.state returns 1, which I presume means its open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that your query is an INSERT query, you can use Connection.Execute instead of RecordSet.Open.

Sample:

```
    Dim recordsAffected As Long
    Call dbConn
    cn.Execute SQLQueryfeld(s), recordsAffected
    Debug.Print "Number of inserted rows: " & recordsAffected
```

Comment: Where in that does it specify which query to execute?

Comment: {recordset_object}.Open() is only ever used for SELECT statements because the results thereof are used to populate the recordset object that .Open() is called on.  Indeed, any attempt to update data has to use an .Execute() and not an .Open().

Answer (score 0):

I just modify GTG 's answer

```
Dim recordsAffected As Long
Call dbConn
cn.Execute SQLQueryfeld(s), recordsAffected
Debug.Print "Number of inserted rows: " & recordsAffected
```

Your variable SqlQueryFeild should be insert statement for example

```
Insert into table X values("df")
```